# How to add an image in page-header?

Tags: magento2, header

**How can I add an image in my page-header though _module.less?** I can change the background color.

Is this the correct way to call an image?

```
background-image: url("@{base-url}/images/bg.png")
```

full link to

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less
```

where should the image be stored?

Answer (score 0):

use `background-image: url('@{baseDir}images/cards.png');`

An image will be accesible in `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images`

Comment: where do i upload the image initially?

Comment: <theme_dir>/web/images -> app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/web/images

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an style in your theme.
And add a style similar to this one that I have.
The image should be in pub/media folder.
 .page-header {
        background-image: 
           url('http://52.191.248.208/rootfolder/pub/media/wysiwyg/header.jpg'); 
    }